# OpenMP; action between nested loops

Tags: c++, nested, openmp, nested-loops

So, I have roughly this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10000; ++i) {
    doAction(i);
    for (int j = 0; j != 10000; ++j) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want to parallellize it using OpenMP. As I understand, a simple `collapse` won't do in this case; my attempts to use separate `#pragma omp for`s have borne no fruit either. Is there a simple way to parallelize this easily or do I have to resort to calling `doAction` `i*j` times?

Comment: How about replacing != by < ?

Comment: @tim18 What is that supposed to do? I always assumed they are equivalent in this context. Also, I don't see how this is related to the nested-loop part of the question

Comment: **[A]:** Do you consider a call to a `doAction( i );` function to represent the *(cit.) "action **between** nested loops"*? **[B]:** How did you come to an idea that the `doAction( i )` code gets called **`i * j`** times? **[C]:** What is the actual processing inside `...`? MCVE-code should represent a reproducible example. How to validate such piece of code, without a chance to confirm / reject possibility to arrange a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** or true-**`[PARALLEL]`** code-execution, when this piece of the MCVE-code is actually missing?

Comment: @user3666197. Ugh. It's not literally between, but it is the best name I can think of. I do realize it is called `i` times; however, the only way I know how to parallellize it is by moving `doAction` inside both loops, which would mean a lot of unnecessary work. As for the MCVE --- this is just me trying to understand OpenMP; the `...` might as well be `printf("%d\n", i*j)`, it's not important.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. You need to provide more code. The best is if you can provide the code you are having a problem or another example which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to parallelize, only use OpenMP for the outer loop.

Parallelizing stuff all the way down isn’t a good thing, because thread synchronization & task scheduling overhead. When you split a large CPU bound task into pieces for parallel execution, ideally the pieces should be as large as possible while using all available CPU cores most of the time.

P.S. If you have OpenMP 4, for the inner loop, you might want to `#pragma omp simd` instead of `parallel`. The outer loop should still be `parallel`. This way you'll use both kinds of parallelism at the same time, the outer loop parallelized across cores, the inner loop parallelized across SIMD lanes. Theoretically, that's often the fastest way to compute stuff.

Comment: This is a good answer. While it doesn't go into detail - the recommendation is right. Parallelize as fine grain (inner loops) as necessary (for exposing enough separate work items and load balance), but parallelize as coarse grain as possible (for keeping overhead small). It puzzles me why this was down-voted.